# UICollectionView using custom UICollectionViewLayout not center aligned

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have a UICollectionView which is linked to a custom UICollectionViewLayout (code below) which has horizontal scroll and paging enabled. I got this code from somewhere on the net to properly implement paging on a UICollectionView. Everything works fine except that it is not properly center aligned. Attached are screenshots on iPhone 5 and iPhone 6. I have tried changing constraints and the size of the UICollectionView.

iPhone 5:https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yvgt1.png
iPhone 6: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iTQhG.png

The left margin (spacing) is perfect whereas the right side is the one creating the problem.

Custom UICollectionViewLayout class

```
class HorizontalCollectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout {


    private var cellWidth = 90
    private var cellHeight = 90
     override func prepareLayout() {

    }


     override func collectionViewContentSize() -> CGSize {
        let numberOfPages = Int(ceilf(Float(cellCount) / Float(cellsPerPage)))
        let width = numberOfPages * Int(boundsWidth)
        return CGSize(width: CGFloat(width), height: boundsHeight)
    }

     override func layoutAttributesForElementsInRect(rect: CGRect) -> [AnyObject]? {
        var allAttributes = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()

        for (var i = 0; i < cellCount; ++i) {
            let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: i, inSection: 0)
            let attr = createLayoutAttributesForCellAtIndexPath(indexPath)

            allAttributes.append(attr)
        }

        return allAttributes
    }

     override func layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes! {
        return createLayoutAttributesForCellAtIndexPath(indexPath)
    }

   override func shouldInvalidateLayoutForBoundsChange(newBounds: CGRect) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    private func createLayoutAttributesForCellAtIndexPath(indexPath:NSIndexPath)
        -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes {
            let layoutAttributes = UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes(forCellWithIndexPath: indexPath)
            layoutAttributes.frame = createCellAttributeFrame(indexPath.row)
            return layoutAttributes
    }

    private var boundsWidth:CGFloat {
        return self.collectionView!.bounds.size.width
    }

    private var boundsHeight:CGFloat {
        return self.collectionView!.bounds.size.height
    }

    private var cellCount:Int {
        return self.collectionView!.numberOfItemsInSection(0)
    }

    private var verticalCellCount:Int {
        return Int(floorf(Float(boundsHeight) / Float(cellHeight)))
    }

    private var horizontalCellCount:Int {
        return Int(floorf(Float(boundsWidth) / Float(cellWidth)))
    }

    private var cellsPerPage:Int {
        return verticalCellCount * horizontalCellCount
    }

    private func createCellAttributeFrame(row:Int) -> CGRect {
        let frameSize = CGSize(width: cellHeight, height: cellWidth)
        let frameX = calculateCellFrameHorizontalPosition(row)
        let frameY = calculateCellFrameVerticalPosition(row)
        return CGRectMake(frameX, frameY, frameSize.width, frameSize.height)
    }

    private func calculateCellFrameHorizontalPosition(row:Int) -> CGFloat {
        let columnPosition = row % horizontalCellCount
        let cellPage = Int(floorf(Float(row) / Float(cellsPerPage)))
        return CGFloat(cellPage * Int(boundsWidth) + columnPosition * Int(cellWidth))
    }

    private func calculateCellFrameVerticalPosition(row:Int) -> CGFloat {
        let rowPosition = (row / horizontalCellCount) % verticalCellCount
        return CGFloat(rowPosition * Int(cellHeight))
    }

}
```

Comment: Where do you set the width of your UICollectionView? It looks like it might be the same width judging from the iPhone 5 and 6 pictures. Can you print out the frame of the UICollectionView in `viewDidAppear`?

Comment: Do you mean `println(self.collectionView.frame)`?

Comment: Yes, or just `println(self.collectionView)` which gives the frame

Comment: iPhone 5: `(16.0, 94.0, 584.0, 498.0)`, iPhone 6: `(16.0, 94.0, 584.0, 498.0)`. Same for both

Comment: That's the problem, your collection view is a fixed size (not with the layout). I assume you're using interface builder? If so, pin the collection view's left (trailing) edge to the right side of the screen. Auto layout will make sure the collection view fills the entire screen. There are a number of good tutorials on google if you need help with autolayout

Comment: I tried adding constraints, but the space on